# Functions: Returning min value in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm having are hard time understanding dictionary functions. The function I'm trying to write needs to find the closest location (given in the dictionary) of where the current place is and return it. I'm told there's a distance formula involved, but not sure how to implement it into the function dictionary. When nothing is found, it should return none.

```
def closest_location(d, place, now):
        close_lst = []# New list
        for d in closest.place():
            for d in closest.now():
                if now != place:
                    return None
                elif now <= place: #If location at now is less than place we want to go to...
                    close_val = now - place
                close_lst.append(close_val)
        return(min(d, key=close_lst.get))# returns closest value in list?
```

Tests:

```
check that closest({(3,1):'gas', (1,4):'gas', (2,1):'food', (5,5):'food'},'food',(5,5)) == (5,5).
check that closest({(3,1):'gas', (1,4):'gas', (2,1):'food', (5,5):'food'},'hotel',(1,4)) == None.
```

Comment: what are `closest.what()` and `closest.now()` ? where are those defined?

Comment: Looks like a Euclidean (x,y) plane?  [Distance formula](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/DistanceFormula.shtml)

Comment: Yes, simple (x,y).

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: Also there is nothing special to dictionary functions if by that you mean the `.items()`, `.keys()`, `.values()`, etc. They are just used to iterate through dict items and thats all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the tuples are x,y coordinates on a grid, the distance formula is given by Pythagoras:

```
(x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2 = distance^2
```

We'll just pull that out into it's own function for readability.

```
from math import sqrt
def find_distance(a,b):
    ax, ay = a
    bx, by = b
    return sqrt((ax-bx)**2 + (ay-by)**2)

def closest_location(d, place, now):
    locations = [loc for loc, attraction in d.items() if attraction==place]
    if not locations:
        return None
    else:
        return min(locations, key=lambda x: find_distance(x, now))
```